# Parse local json to UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file so I can use it's contents as `NSStrings` and display in `UILabels` throughout my application.

**My JSON:**

```
{
    "CustomText": [
        {
            "bodyText": "This is the body text",
            "loginText": "This is the loginText",
            "extraText": "This is the extra text"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My code:**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"json"];

NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSArray *customStrings = json[@"CustomText"];
NSString *body = [customStrings valueForKey:@"bodyText"];
NSString *login = [customStrings valueForKey:@"loginText"];
self.labelText.text = body;
```

I'm not sure why it breaks, I have looks and surprisingly didn't find much on how to best use a local `JSON` file.  Any help would be great.

Error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8080781740'

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? "Breaks"?

Comment: i am getting this errorTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8080781740'

Comment: `[[customStrings objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"bodyText"]` and the same for `loginText`?

Comment: Thats great thank you, is this an acceptable way to parse my son data?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"json"];


NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSArray *customStrings = json[@"CustomText"];
NSString *body = [[customStrings objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"bodyText"];
NSString *login = [[customStrings objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"loginText"];
self.labelText.text = body;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keypath

```
    NSString * body = [json valueForKeyPath:@"CustomText.bodyText"];
    self.labelText.text = body;
```